# Objects move when an image is loaded

Tags: javascript, html, css

The image below shows the layout that I want to be constant.
When selecting a row in a table, it will update the image via javascript.
Sometimes this works and other time the image updates, however the Print Stats button moves below the search input. When I select an image that works, the button goes back. I can not figure out why or how to fix it.

````
    css
    .grid-container {
      display: grid;
      grid-template-columns: 500px 150px ;
    }

    #image_src {
        height:130px;
        width:auto;
        border: 5px solid #555;
    }

    Javascript
    document.getElementById('image_src').src = img_path;


    html
    <div class="myDiv" >
        <div class="grid-container">
            <div>
                <h3>Player List and Statistics</h3>
                MP (Matches played) <br>
              Click on Header Column to sort. <br>  
              <input style="font-size: 18px;" id="myInput" type="text" placeholder="Search for player">
                <button  class="btnSC" type="button" id="create_chart" onclick="create_chart_adm()" >Chart Scores</button>
                

                <button class="btnPrint" style="font-size: 18px;"type="button" id="print_stats" onclick="do_print_stats()" >Print Stats</button>
            </div>
            <div>
                    <img style="margin-top: 10px" id="image_src" src="tennis.png" onerror="imgError()" alt="Profile Picture" >
            </div>
            
        </div>
```[![Desired layout][1]][1]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/glcWe.jpg
````